# Añadir título a documento PDF con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, pdf

He descargado este [ejemplo](https://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/table-export-to-pdf) para exportar una tabla a *PDF*. Me gustaría añadir un título personalizado y no sé cómo hacerlo, esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#exportButton").click(function() {
    // parse the HTML table element having an id=exportTable
    var content = 'This is a sample PDF created using jQuery. Find more examples of what you can do with DocRaptor <a href="https://docraptor.com/">https://docraptor.com/</a> or contact support@docraptor.com with any questions.';

    var dataSource = shield.DataSource.create({
      data: "#exportTable",
      schema: {
        type: "table",
        fields: {
          Name: {
            type: String
          },
          Age: {
            type: Number
          },
          Email: {
            type: String
          }
        }
      }
    });

    // when parsing is done, export the data to PDF
    dataSource.read().then(function(data) {
      var pdf = new shield.exp.PDFDocument({
        author: "PrepBootstrap",
        created: new Date()
      });

      pdf.addPage("a4", "portrait");

      pdf.table(
        50,
        50,
        data, [{
            field: "Name",
            title: "Person Name",
            width: 200
          },
          {
            field: "Age",
            title: "Age",
            width: 50
          },
          {
            field: "Email",
            title: "Email Address",
            width: 200
          }
        ], {
          content
        }; {
          margins: {
            top: 50,
            left: 50
          }
        }
      );

      pdf.saveAs({
        fileName: "PrepBootstrapPDF"
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: con un titulo te refieres a el nombre del archivo?

Comment: Me refiero a agregar informacion adicional en hoja pdf que se muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Si con título te refieres a nombre del archivo, donde pone `fileName` pones el nombre que desees al documento:

```
pdf.saveAs({
    fileName: "nombreDelDocumentoQueQuiera"
  });
```